# Confused about syntax of map::emplace

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

Given

```
std::map<int, int> myMap;
```

Which of the following statements

```
myMap.emplace(1, 2);
myMap.emplace({1, 2});
myMap.emplace(std::make_pair<int,int>(1,2));
```

are valid, and why?  It seems to me that the second (with `{}`s) should certainly work if the third does.

Comment: `myMap.emplace(1,2);` is not invalid and works fine for me.

Comment: Why is the second invalid, then?

Comment: which compiler ? `emplace` won't work for g++ 4.6.1 or older AFAIK

Comment: g++ 4.8.1 and clang++ 3.3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`myMap.emplace(1,2);` is not invalid and works fine for me.

`myMap.emplace({1,2});` is invalid as `emplace` **forwards** it's arguments to create an object in-place instead of taking an object of type `value_type` (from the map) itself as an argument. Since it is not taking an object of the target type (the `std::pair`), the compiler can't use the initializer list to create that object.

If the `std::pair` would be constructed by the call to `emplace` directly, you would not benefit from `emplace` at all and it's existance would be mostly pointless.

`myMap.emplace(std::make_pair<int,int>(1,2));` is valid, but probably not what you want. You want

```
myMap.insert(std::make_pair(1,2));
```

or

```
myMap.insert(decltype(myMap)::value_type(1,2));
```

as `emplace` would not offer any benefit for when you already have a `std::pair`.

Comment: What is the difference between `{1,2}` (basically calling the constructor, right?) and `std::make_pair(1,2)`?

Comment: Nope, I was wrong, deduction simply fails for `{1,2}`. It's a non-deduced context as per [temp.deduct.call]/1.

Comment: @thirtythreeforty `{1,2}` calling the constructor **of what**? That is the problem here, that is why it doesn't work. The compiler can't forward `{1,2}` until in the end it figures out what the type to construct should be.

Comment: @DyP I think that's the reason why there is no way to forward it as an `initializer_list`.

Comment: I think you could also write `myMap.emplace<decltype(myMap)::value_type>({1,2});`. As the braced-init-list is just a non-deduced context, specifying the template argument makes it work.

Comment: You could also forward it as an `initializer_list` by explicitly specifying the template argument.

Comment: @DyP There are some possible options for that, yes, but what would be the benefit over the other and simpler options?

Comment: @DanielFrey There's no benefit :) Well here it's ill-formed, anyway. But for more complex data types, you could reduce the amount of instantiations. `push_back` should work as well, though, and doesn't require the explicit argument.

Comment: @thirtythreeforty make_pair creates a pair<int, int>, while myMap::value_type is a pair<const int, int>, so it will require a extra conversion that copies the elements before it can store it in the map.  Probably won't matter for ints; can certainly matter for more expensive types.

Comment: Ah, subtle but important.